# How to suppress specific Gendarme rules at project or assembly level

Tags: .net, code-analysis, static-analysis, gendarme

I need to suppress unwanted gendarme rules for the whole assembly of my project or even for individual projects. Is there any option available? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an **.ignore** file for your project.

E.g. to ignore a specific rule for all assemblies (e.g. a project) you can add the following lines in your ignore file:

```
R: Gendarme.Rules.Smells.AvoidSwitchStatementsRule
A: *
```

Here's a link to Gendarme's [ignore](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/blob/master/gendarme/self-test.ignore) file used for it's self-check.